# Allowing one page to be accessed by Anonymous user in restricted site

Tags: 7, webforms, users

My site is for logged in users only as "View published content" is unchecked for Anonymous users.

Now the problem is that there is one page that I created which shows a form for a user to fill for applying for a membership. It's been created in Webform and I want to show it to Anonymous user.

Naturally, this page is currently restricted and I am confused as to how to show this page to an Anonymous user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [content access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) provides per node access.

Comment: Couldn't make this work. I used [Node View Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions) and it worked.